# Is there a direct way to approve or reject manual approvals via the GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

Is there a direct way to approve or reject manual approvals via the GitHub API? I am writing a script that will bulk reject a group of approvals in the event a PR was pushed to master with some errors that need to change but dont want to spend time going through and rejecting each job. ChatGPT suggests as of its last update that there is no way to do it but that I am not sure if Github API has been updated since then and I cant find anything in the Github Docs.

Comment: What do you mean by "approving/rejecting a manual approval"? Do you want to overturn a PR review decision, or what approval are we talking about?

Comment: So Github Actions is used to deploy our Terraform but once a PR is merged, we require manual approval or rejection of the tf plans before deploying the infrastructure. Sometimes, an error in the code is missed after the PR is merged, so I want to be able to bulk reject all of the associated jobs that would normally need manual intervention to reject or approve using a Github API call. @BenjaminW.

Comment: What exactly requires the approval? is it for an [Actions deployment](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/reviewing-deployments), linked to an environment?

Comment: I was actually able to get what I needed to work @BenjaminW.